# Launching an application using browser?

Tags: android

I want to launch an application in the phone by clicking its link in the browser..How can I do this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your application respond to a tailor-made intent described in your manifest file, like this :

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="myserver.com" android:pathPrefix="/directory"/>
```

Your application will then respond to links http://myserver.com/directory.

In your activity, you can then get the url by calling .getData on the intent.

Comment: can you give the complete code code for launching the installed package from the browser

Answer (score 0):

As Jean described writing your own intent filter is the way to go, but you probably want to use your own private scheme based on your app name, as the built in browser will probably intercept http in many cases.

```
<activity android:name=".main"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="helloworld" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then to trigger it, in html:

```
<a href="helloworld://somedata/urlformated">Click here to launch app</a>
```

To access the url data, in your activity `onResume`, do something like:

```
Uri launchURI = getIntent().getData();
```

You can parse out the data using the various Uri methods. Keep in mind that there will be an Intent even for normal launch so you need to handle that case. Doing this in `onResume` supports both the case where your app was already running and was launched.

Comment: plz tell me how to get the url in my application

Comment: thanz....its working...just as i need...bt i want to show in mobile browser whether that application is installed or not...if not installed show that in an alert......is that posible??